# Unit testing visual c++ code throws when deleting pointer

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, pointers, visual-c++

I am currently unit testing unmanaged visual c++ code in visual studio 2010.
My solution is structured as following:

```
<Solution>
  - [0] Static library project (visual c++, no clr)
  - [1] Project that's using [0] (visual c++, no clr, referencing [0])
  - [2] Unit Test Project (dynamic library, /clr, referencing [0])
</Solution>
```

**`Project [0]` is being tested by `Project [2]` and contains `SomeClass`:**

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass() {}
    int Testme() { return 42; }
};
```

**In `Project [2]` I am testing `SomeClass` as following, and this works:**

```
[TestClass]
public ref class SomeClassUnitTests
{
public:
    [TestMethod]
    void TestmeReturns42()
    {
        SomeClass sc;
        Assert::AreEqual<int>(42, sc.Testme());
    }
};
```

But when I allocate the memory for `SomeClass` on the heap and only when I afterwards call delete on it, a message pops up showing that the heap was corrupt/invalid.

```
[TestClass]
public ref class SomeClassUnitTests
{
public:
    [TestMethod]
    void TestmeReturns42()
    {
        SomeClass *ptr = new SomeClass();
        Assert::AreEqual<int>(42, ptr->Testme());

        // Without following line, everything works:
        if (ptr) delete ptr;
    }
};
```

> What could be the issue causing the Tests to throw right here, and why does allocating memory with 'new' work, but deleting doesn't?

Comment: Is there a mismatch of Debug and Release builds, or are they all the same?

Comment: You gave me the missing clue, because I had somehow (and only in the debug version) included MFC into the test project, for I had used it inside the project being tested... So I removed all the MFC related code from both the test-project and the project being tested, and now the delete call doesn't crash the program anymore. I still have no clue why including MFC causes this problem though...